# Adding scrollbar to an activeX control in MFC

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, mfc, activex

I'm trying to create an activeX control using Microsoft Foundation Class Library.

I have created the control. It's a graph control. I have placed some buttons on the control as well.

I am trying to add a scrollbar to my control using `CScrollBar` class.

I create the control using `CScrollBar::Create` method. I can see the control when use my activeX control in an application.

I have added the `OnHScroll` method to my control class. This derives from `COleControl` class .

When I scroll I use `CScrollBar::GetScrollPos` to get the scroll position which I always returns zero.

Here is the code for creating the scrollbar in activeX control.

Code for Control in MainClass.h file:

```
private:
CScrollBar m_HScrollBar;

protected:
afx_msg void OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar); 
DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Code for Control in MainClass.cpp in `OnCreate()` method for creating the scrollbar:

```
m_HScrollBar.Create(SBS_HORZ | WS_CHILD| WS_VISIBLE , CRect(rcBottomStrip.left  ,
rcBottomStrip.bottom  ,
rcBottomStrip.right ,
rcBottomStrip.bottom  + (tHeight*3)/125),this, 315);

m_HScrollBar.SetScrollRange(0, 2048);

SCROLLINFO ScrollInfo;
ScrollInfo.cbSize = sizeof(ScrollInfo);
ScrollInfo.fMask = SIF_RANGE;        
ScrollInfo.nMin = 0;                
ScrollInfo.nMax = 1128;              
ScrollInfo.nPage = 100;              
ScrollInfo.nPos = 0;                
ScrollInfo.nTrackPos = 0;          
m_HScrollBar.SetScrollInfo(&ScrollInfo);
m_HScrollBar.ShowScrollBar(TRUE);
m_HScrollBar.EnableWindow();
m_HScrollBar.EnableAutomation();
```

In `OnHScroll` method to return the scroll position and moving the scrollbar:

```
int CurPos = m_HScrollBar.GetScrollPos();
m_HScrollBar.SetScrollPos(CurPos);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the CScrollBar and used HWND instead.
So my code changed like this:

//MainClass.h

```
HWND m_wndHScrollBar;
```

//MainClass.cpp

```
m_wndHScrollBar = (CreateWindowEx( 
                    0,                      // no extended styles 
                    SCROLLBAR,           // scroll bar control class 
                    (PTSTR) NULL,           // no window text 
                    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE   // window styles  
                        | SBS_HORZ,         // horizontal scroll bar style 
                    left,              // horizontal position 
                    bottom, // vertical position 
                    right,             // width of the scroll bar 
                    height,               // height of the scroll bar
                    m_hWnd,             // handle to main window 
                    (HMENU) ID_HSCROLLBAR,           // no menu 
                    GetModuleHandle(NULL),                // instance owning this window 
                    (PVOID) NULL            // pointer not needed 
                ));
```