# draw scroll bar to mfc activeX control Visual studio 2012(c++)..?

Tags: c++, mfc

how can I draw scroll bar on to mfc activex control, I am using visual studio 2012....

```
void CCircCtrl::OnDraw(CDC* pdc, const CRect& rcBounds, const CRect&)
{
    CBrush* pOldBrush;
    CBrush bkBrush(TranslateColor(GetBackColor()));
    CPen* pOldPen;
    CRect rc = rcBounds;
    CFont* pOldFont;
    CScrollBar cscrollbar;
    TEXTMETRIC tm;
    const CString& strCaption = InternalGetText();
    RECT scrollbarrect = {rcBounds.left,rcBounds.bottom-20,rcBounds.right,rcBounds.bottom};
    cscrollbar.Create(SBS_HORZ|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE, scrollbarrect,this,NULL);
    cscrollbar.SetScrollRange(0, 2048);
    SCROLLINFO ScrollInfo;
    ScrollInfo.cbSize = sizeof(ScrollInfo); 
    ScrollInfo.fMask = SIF_RANGE; 
    ScrollInfo.nMin = 0;                
    ScrollInfo.nMax = 1128;              
    ScrollInfo.nPage = 100;              
    ScrollInfo.nPos = 0;                
    ScrollInfo.nTrackPos = 0;          
    cscrollbar.SetScrollInfo(&ScrollInfo);
    cscrollbar.ShowScrollBar(TRUE);
    cscrollbar.EnableWindow();
    cscrollbar.EnableAutomation();
```

this is how I do it but the problem is the scroll bar is drawing without any problem but it is non responsive...

please help

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is'nt possible to add scroll features to an ActiveX Control if it doesn't support it.

May be it is easier to create a new window that has scroll functionality and place the ActiveX control inside this new parent window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483211/adding-scrollbar-to-an-activex-control-in-mfc?rq=1 in this post they showed that it is possible, i tried that myself and the scroll bar is showing when i tested it, but it is non-responsive...

Comment: Just creating a scrollbar is one thing. Add handler to WM_HSCROLL/WM_VSCROLL and react on what they are telling you...